# ¿Cómo poner un TextView a la derecha de un ImageView, dentro de un LinearLayout?

Tags: android-imageview, xamarin.android, textview

Cómo podría alinear en la parte del primer layout, donde dice "Cambiar Clave"  para que quede a la derecha del imageview (la imagen de la llave)

Aquí dejó mi código:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#6094bc"
        android:layout_marginTop="25px"
        android:layout_marginRight="15px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/key"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="2px"
            android:padding="2px"
            android:paddingTop="2px"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#D3D3D3"
            android:textSize="40px"
            android:id="@+id/lblCam"
            android:text="Cambiar Clave:" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es tan sencillo como cambiar el valor de la propiedad `android:orientation="vertical"` a `horizontal`.

```
<LinearLayout
    <!-- solo cambie el valor de vertical a horizontal-->
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#6094bc"
    android:layout_marginTop="25px"
    android:layout_marginRight="15px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```